# 8086 Machine Language: Simple Program Not Working

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox, emu8086

Trying to display my name and input of a character through machine language of NASM through DOSBox. It is very simple but I'm having trouble with the code. My code is listed below.

The instructions are to write an 8086 program which will:

- Display your name on one line
- On the next line, display a ‘?’
- Read a character from the keyboard
- Display a second message and the character that immediately follows in the ASCII character sequence.

Here is my code so far. For some reason, it will not work as well as I'm missing how to get the character that follows in the ASCII character sequence.

Will you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
And if I'm on the right track?
As well as how to read the new ASCII character?

HERE'S MY CODE SO FAR:

```
      org 100h
      section .data
      msg   DB "Name of Person"
      char  DB '?'
      char1 DB ' '
      msg2  DB 0dh, 0ah, 'The following character in sequence is:  '
      char3 DB ' ','$'
   section .text
  Start: 
      mov  dx, [msg]     ;get message
      mov  ah, 09h       ;display string function
      int  21h           ;display message
  ;input a character
      mov  ah, 1         ;read char fcn
      int  21h           ;input char into AL
      mov  [char1], al   ;store character
  ;display in same line 
      mov  dx, [char1]   ;read char1
      mov  ah, 1         ;display character
      int  21h           ;display message
   ;display on next line next character
      mov  dx, msg2      ;get last line message
      int  21h           ;display message
  Exit:
      mov  ah, 4Ch       ;DOS function: Exit program
      mov  al, 0         ;return exit code value
      int  21h           ;Call DOS. Terminate program
```

Comment: No code was posted.

Comment: @ScottHunter edited

Comment: @zx485 edited  .

Comment: Please make a habit of including code as text in a _code section_  and not as image. The latter is quite useless for forming a [mcve], so it's better to avoid it.

Comment: Have a look at [Ralph Browns' interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm) to learn how to use `INT 21h` correctly. This should help you big time. P.S.: Don't forget to set the data segment `DS` immediately after `Start` if you're not creating a `.COM` file like indicated by using `org 100h`(`.COM`), but opposed by using sections (`.EXE`).

Comment: Also remember to either count out the string length or include a terminating character.

Comment: there are many problems with your code, how about taking a step back and first checking some working examples/tutorials, and then slowly modifying those one step at time, observing what works, and what not and why...?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> org 100h
> ```

This `ORG 100h` directive indicates that your goal is to get a .COM program. Since the task calls for a **simple** program this is the right choice. You don't need to worry about initializing the segment registers and you don't need to use sections like `.data` or `.text`. There's but one thing you need to be aware of: If you put the data (messages, ...) **before** the code they will mistakenly be executed! Therefore it's best to put them **below** the code, far down in the program. That's a safe place.

> **1**. Display your name on one line
>
> ```
> mov  dx, [msg]     ;get message
> mov  ah, 09h       ;display string function
> int  21h           ;display message
> ```

For this DOS output function you need to provide an address in `DX`. When using the NASM assembler an instruction like `mov dx, [msg]` will fetch the 2 bytes stored at the address *msg*. That is not what you want in this case! The correct instruction is `mov dx, msg`, so **without the square brackets**.
Secondly this DOS output function expects the message to end with a dollar sign **$** that you didn't provide.

> **2**. On the next line, display a ‘?’

You can easily combine this with outputting your name. See below code.

> **3**. Read a character from the keyboard

You do this just fine.

> **4**. Display a second message, and the character that immediately follows in the ASCII character sequence.

You get the next ASCII character simply by *incrementing* the number you got in step **3**.

---

Since this is indeed a very simple program, it's next to impossible to not write the whole code.
Even so, you can learn a lot from it. Please do pay attention to the extra comments below.

```
org 100h

mov  dx, msg1
mov  ah, 09h       ;display string function
int  21h

mov  ah, 01h       ;read char function
int  21h           ;leaves char in AL
inc  al
mov  [char], al    ;store N E X T character 

mov  dx, msg2
mov  ah, 09h       ;display string function
int  21h

mov  ax, 4C00h     ;DOS function to exit program with return exit code value
int  21h

msg1  DB 'Dillon Shotwell',13,10,'?$'
msg2  DB 13,10,'The following character in sequence is: '
char  DB 0,13,10,'$'
```

- The DOS input function 01h already printed the character on the screen (this is called `echo`), so it's not useful to repeat this action.
- Because the terminating **$** for the second message is placed behind the incremented *char* the whole thing was outputted with a single call to DOS function 09h.
- Ending your final message with a carriage return/linefeed is definitely nicer.
- Try to avoid writing redundant comments. They make reading and understanding the program harder.
- Whenever possible combine operations like `mov ah, 4Ch` and `mov al, 0` that can just as easily be written like `mov ax, 4C00h`. The accompanying comment will clarify it enough.